# In Google App Engine, how does one use python to query by boolean?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, jinja2

"checked" is assigned BooleanProperty and has a default value of False.

in a post method, I reset "checked" if the entity's checkbox is checked

```
def post(self):
    sells = SellModel.all()

    boxcount = 0
    for sell in sells:
        checkbox = self.request.get('checkbox')
        if checkbox:
            sell.checked = True
            boxcount += 1

    if boxcount == 0:
        error = "check at least one box"
        self.render("buy.html", error = error, sells = sells)
    else:     
        self.redirect('/contact')
```

then I tried the following calls

```
cart = SellModel.all().filter("checked =", True)

cart = SellModel.all().filter("checked !=", False)

cart = SellModel.all().filter("checked >", False)
```

Which all don't work. However, when I queried for when checked is false, as in

```
cart = SellModel.all().filter("checked =", False)
```

it works...what is happening? i thought placing "sell.checked = True" in a for loop like that would set that sell entry's "checked" to true

Comment: The first query should work.  Are you sure there are actually values in the datastore with checked == True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized sell.checked = True doesn't actually update the object. I added 
    sell.put()
and it worked.